# Why is packagekitd is running?

Tags: apt

I look into processes on my laptop. It is T420. There is one process in top five. It is packagekitd. `/usr/lib/packagekit/packagekitd`. I don't understand why do I need packagekitd running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packagekitd is responsible for handling package operations (installation, uninstallation, updating, etc...) for AppCenter. It runs in the background so it can check for updates and await commands to perform actions via AppCenter.

There is a command called `pkmon` that will show you what actions packagekitd is performing in the background if you wanted to check.

Comment: For some reason it takes too much CPU in my opinion.

Comment: When it's taking a lot of CPU, try the `pkmon` command to see if it's doing anything it shouldn't be. Report a bug against the AppCenter github page with some detailed information if you think something is wrong.